# synchronous Client thread Pool with jersey

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, httpclient, sun

Hi I have to design send synchronous POST request using thread pool.I have used sun jersey client. And then add this configuration to jersey client.https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig.html#PROPERTY_THREADPOOL_SIZE But This is Asynchronous request thread pool.Is there any way to use synchronous request thread pool.This is the way i created client.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
        config.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_THREADPOOL_SIZE, 20);
        jerseyClient = Client.create(config);
```

I need thread pool which contains 10 threads and using that thread pool send synchronous request.Is that OK to use `ExecutorService` or any http client ??

Thanks